# Is a stochastic process being Markovian or Martingale completely determined by its law?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Suppose a stochastic process is Markovian. Let $L$ be its law on its sample path space (note that here I assume its initial distribution is known, not just conditional distributions). If there is another stochastic process with the same law $L$, will it be also Markovian? In other words, is being Markovian completely determined by the law of a stochastic process?

Similar question for Martingale. Is being Martingale completely determined by the law of a stochastic process?

Is it possible to point out what kinds of properties of a stochastic process are determined by its law completely, and what cannot?
Note that I have asked if sample path being continuous a.e. is determined completely by the law [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293006/is-a-stochastic-process-being-continuous-a-e-completely-determined-by-its-law).

Thanks and regards!

Comment: See here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/78397/markov-property-determined-by-just-the-law-or-also-the-realization